# How do I turn off "auto-scrolling" in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

My problem is when I open an Explorer window and attempt to double-click an icon with a filename that is not fully displayed, my click is not fast enough to open the file before windows scrolls to the left to make the filename more visible.

What is this called and how do I turn it off?

Comment: Here is a link to provide clarity for what I am asking http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/double-clicking-file-scrolls-rather-than-executing/0dddb413-1fef-4e7a-a238-4e8b42ae5e1c

Comment: Have you increased the setting for double-click time? Many parts of Windows understand that setting, and will wait longer. It's a setting in the Control Panel, IIRC under "Mouse".

Comment: @MSalters No I haven't tried that one yet, but wouldn't expect it would work since it's the first click that is responsible for making the icon move to the left.

Comment: The point is that Windows must wait for the double-click time before it knows that the first click is a single click. Computers are fast enough to move that icon in a nanosecond, and no-one can click that fast.

Comment: @MSalters I tried it.  It didn't work.  It was a good idea though.

Comment: The currently selected "solution" is not an answer to the question, at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I'm doing this on Windows XP, and using an Icon view (since the Fonts folder doesn't do this in List view).

Assuming you have a file *cropped* out by the current Windows Explorer window (see the bottom part).

[image: Cropped icons]

As soon as I pass (or in your case, single-click) on one of the *cropped* icons, the contents shift upwards in order to show the entirety of the file you selected.

[image: Window adjusting itself]

I can't find a current synonym for this action, and I find more complaints about Windows 7 having the sorting algorithm on by default than this. While I can conceivably think Windows has a registry entry that controls this behavior, Windows is actually doing you **The Right Thing**.

For solutions, you have two good ones:

1. Use an alternative view. Details can give you the benefit of having
   a list with the added benefits of increased information. It's trivial to do it, just right click on the empty space, go to View, and select Details.

   [image]

   (The picture was taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27314d0a-9c70-4b79-93e7-23fe60e7e374/windows-87vista-explorer-petition-please-allow-us-to-disable-auto-refresh-auto-sorting-and) and although it has some things marked **that shouldn't be** for the purpose of this question, it was the best pic I could find).
2. Resize the window such as at least a 3rd row appears:

   [image: 3rd row prevents this behavior]
3. It seems a tool like TweakUI was for XP exists for Windows 7 / Vista. In it I found an option called *Disable full row select items* that might be what you were looking for. The tool is called [Ultimate Windows Tweaker](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-v2-a-tweak-ui-for-windows-7-vista)

UPDATE:
Detailing the **Details** view

[image: Details]

When in **Details** you can double click the separator between the filename and the other column. This automatically adjusts to the maximum name length present in the folder (that in my case, was the Meiryo Bold font).

[image: Details - extended]

Comment: Wow this is a very nice answer! The problem with solution #1 is win7 doesn't have auto sort or auto arrange listed as an option to turn off. With solution #2, suppose those fonts are mp3s and I wanted to listen to california fb, if I try to double-click that icon, it will jump to the left. I think solution #3 may be the only option I have.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I apologize for the misleading picture, but I don't have Windows 7. The fact Windows 7 doesn't have auto sort or auto arrange doesn't alter the answer; that, instead of using a **List** view, you can switch for a **Details** view, that is nearly equal to a **List**, without the problem you described.

Comment: Yes, that may be a solution too, but I've always used the "list" view since win95. In a "details" view, I have 1/3 the filename information as in a "list" view.

Comment: How so? You can always extend the length of the filename field by dragging the field separator.

Comment: Using your pic of fonts as an example, if it were in details view, the list would end at "arial rounded mt bold", which is 1/3 of the list shown in the pic.

Comment: @Randy Please check updated answer.

Comment: Yes, the details view is a solution to the problem, but it is still more work having to scroll down to find the icon I want while the list view would show it by default. I may as well keep the list view and scroll icons all the way to the left before I select it.  It would be the same amount of work.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach If you have a better answer than mine, feel free to post it. Also, if you could mention the aspects of my answer that felt poorer to you, I could try to fix them.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: I've already stated what's wrong: you're not answering the question, you're apparently not even understanding the question. See http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/why-does-the-contents-of-windows-explorer/d7f82ba7-cf8c-4cf3-8dec-5c80cdb5c6a6 for more information about the question, or just google it (it's a very common annoyance). As with this SO question at the Microsoft page there is a selected answer, which is not an answer at all. As far as I know there is no fix. The problem (really undesired "help") persist up to and including Windows 8.1.